# How to place a website name above navbar elements inside a header | HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a website name above the navigation bar, but I do not know to do it.

Here are HTML and CSS codes.

{load static} thing inside HTML code is a command to load CSS files inside a django project. But here is no Django involved, just visual styling of HTML and CSS.

If you have any questions I will be super glad to answer

My HTML code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;


}

li, a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  background-color: #24252A;
  justify-content: center;

}

.nav__logo {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;



}

.nav__links{
  list-style: none;



}
.nav__links li {

  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 60px;


}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #008Ba9
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="{%  static  'css/styles.css'  %}">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a class= "nav__logo" href="#">Rose</a>
      <nav>

        <ul class="nav__links">
          <li><a href="#">Женщины</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Акции и конкурсы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подарки</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

my CSS code

Answer (score 0):

Is is it ok or you want some other thing??

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;


}

li, a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  background-color: #24252A;
  justify-content: center;

}

.nav__logo {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;



}

.nav__links{
  list-style: none;



}
.nav__links li {

  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 60px;


}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #008Ba9
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="{%  static  'css/styles.css'  %}">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>

  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>heading</h1>
    <header>
    
      <a class= "nav__logo" href="#">Rose</a>
      <nav>

        <ul class="nav__links">
          <li><a href="#">Женщины</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Акции и конкурсы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подарки</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [answer], its a good idea to explain your solution.

Comment: It is my fault that I did not provide enough of details. So this is not exactly what I need.

You see the "Rose" inside the navigation bar? So I want this Rose to stay above these three texts "Женщины, Подарки" and etc. inside the navigation bar